# How to make a QT widget update modified properties from its parent widget?

Tags: c++, layout, qt4

I've got a QWidget that contains several QLineEdits. When I tell the parent QWidget to change its background color
**dynamically**, I'd like the children (i.e. QLineEdits) to inherit this modification.

Is there an easy (read: one function call) to do this?

If nothing pops up, I think I'll just loop through the children of the QWidget, but when doing this properly I expect to end up with a recursive function with a lot of overhead, that's why I'm asking.

EDITs in Bold face.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking you don't need to worry about "overhead" in dialogs.  Unless you're doing some sort of massive draw operation, UI applications simply don't need a lot of optimizations.  Digging down to all children and changing their background is a relatively fast operation compared to the Qt system itself actually doing the change.

That said, I'd assume there is a way to get what you want but I don't know what it is.  My bet is that it will do exactly what you would anyway.

How are you going about telling it to "change color" btw?  Qt doesn't seem to have operations to do that.  You can assign a background role or change the pallete.  As to the latter:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#palette-prop

Comment: Thanks for the reply! With respect to finding an answer to my question I'll see what others come up with. With respect to actually changing the colors, I'm indeed using ColorRoles and Palettes. If you'd like to know more on that, just give a shout!

Answer (score 0):

If you set the background color using a style sheet assigned to that widget and don't specify any selectors in the CSS, all child widgets will inherit any properties that apply to them.

I found it useful to use a selector that allowed me to target specific widgets for a certain style.

```
QWidget[objectName|="special_color"]
{
   color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

If I used this in a style sheet assigned to a container widget, it would apply the specified color to any child widgets whose name started with "`special_color`" like "`special_colorEditBox1`" no matter how they are nested or contained.

Comment: Does this also work when trying to change the color dynamically? Say I press a button ChangeBackgroundColor, should that button modify the CSS? Is that even possible? (My CSS knowledge does not extend from the HTML into the QT domain...)

Comment: You shouldn't change CSS, you should change object names, but still it requires you to go through all "interested" widgets and change their object name.

Comment: @Kamul Klimek: Thanks! If I understand correctly, this is actually the same as what I described in the question, except it works with CSS instead of QPalettes and QColorRoles.

Comment: @Kamil Klimek: Can you explain why you shouldn't change the CSS to change the colors?

Comment: Well, you're using css property selector: objectName property contains "special_color". Changing objects name from myLineEdit, to myLineEdit_special_color will apply this rule, changing property name back to myLineEdit will undo css rule.

Comment: Oh. Well my intent was that the CSS be assembled in code (as a QString) and applied to the containing widget. When the button in question is clicked, modify the color specified in the CSS and reapply the CSS to the containing widget and all the specially named widgets will change color.